# In PHP how do you access data from multidimensional arrays with multiple keys

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

This is the array:

```
$weatherData = [
    "Chicago" => [45, "fog",   ["Mon" => [44, "fog"], "Tue" => [42, "sleet"], "Wed" => [40, "rain"], "Thu" => [44, "cloudy"], "Fri" => [45, "cloudy"]]],
    "Paris" =>   [73, "sunny", ["Mon" => [75, "sunny"], "Tue" => [75, "sunny"], "Wed" => [68, "cloudy"], "Thu" => [66, "cloudy"], "Fri" => [60, "rain"]]],
    "Calgary" => [-8, "snow",  ["Mon" => [-7, "snow"], "Tue" => [-10, "snow"], "Wed" => [-3, "sleet"], "Thu" => [0, "cloudy"], "Fri" => [3, "sunny"]]]
];
```

I already have a function to output the general info of each city (ex: for Chicago, I outputted "45" and "fog"):

```
function outputBox($weatherData)
{
    foreach ($weatherData as $key => $value) {
        echo "<article class='box'";
        echo "<h1>$key</h1>";
        echo "<div class='weather'>";
        echo "<img src='images/$key.jpg' />";
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<h2>$value[0]</h2>";
        echo "<p>$value[1]</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    outputForecast($weatherData);
}
```

And now I need to output the other info like for Chicago "Mon 44 fog", "Tues 42 sleet"...
So far I got this:

```
function outputForecast($weatherData){

    foreach ($weatherData[1] as $key => $value){
        echo "<section>";
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<h3>$key</h3>";
    }
}
```

I don't know whats the proper code to access those numbers for my loop but it should output the mon-friday details, please help thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hy scoobidydoo, you are close to the solution, but you need to read about the PHP array. It is very interesting to play with the code. Just change both the functions,

Here is the solution:
https://paiza.io/projects/Led6GCYVW6HV1dIZH6MdVQ?language=php

```
function outputBox($weatherData)
{
    foreach ($weatherData as $key => $value) {
        echo "<article class='box'>";
        echo "<h1>$key</h1>";
        echo "<div class='weather'>";
            echo "<img src='images/$key.jpg' />";
            echo "<div>";
            echo "<h2>$value[0]</h2>";
            echo "<p>$value[1]</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</article>";

        outputForecast($value[2]);
        echo '<hr/>';
    }
}

function outputForecast($valueDays){
    echo "<h2>Forecast</h2>";
    foreach ($valueDays as $key => $value){
        echo "<section>";
            echo "<div>";
                echo "<h3>$key</h3>";
                echo "<p>$value[0] - $value[1]</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</section>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this also,

```
function outputBox($weatherData)
{
    foreach ($weatherData as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.", ".$value[0].", ".$value[1].", ".'</br>';
        if(!empty($value[2])){
           foreach ($value[2] as $k1 => $v1) {
               echo '"'.$k1." ".$v1[0]." ".$v1[1].'"';
           }
        }
        echo '</br>';
    }
}

print_r(outputBox($weatherData));
```

OutPut :

```
Chicago, 45, fog, 
"Mon 44 fog""Tue 42 sleet""Wed 40 rain""Thu 44 cloudy""Fri 45 cloudy"
Paris, 73, sunny, 
"Mon 75 sunny""Tue 75 sunny""Wed 68 cloudy""Thu 66 cloudy""Fri 60 rain"
Calgary, -8, snow, 
"Mon -7 snow""Tue -10 snow""Wed -3 sleet""Thu 0 cloudy""Fri 3 sunny"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$weatherData = [
    "Chicago" => [45, "fog", ["Mon" => [44, "fog"], "Tue" => [42, "sleet"], "Wed" => [40, "rain"], "Thu" => [44, "cloudy"], "Fri" => [45, "cloudy"]]],
    "Paris" => [73, "sunny", ["Mon" => [75, "sunny"], "Tue" => [75, "sunny"], "Wed" => [68, "cloudy"], "Thu" => [66, "cloudy"], "Fri" => [60, "rain"]]],
    "Calgary" => [-8, "snow", ["Mon" => [-7, "snow"], "Tue" => [-10, "snow"], "Wed" => [-3, "sleet"], "Thu" => [0, "cloudy"], "Fri" => [3, "sunny"]]]
];

printData($weatherData);

function printData($weatherData)
{
    foreach ($weatherData as $key => $data) {
        echo '****<b>' . $key . ': ' . $data[0];
        echo ' ' . $data[1] . '</b>****<br>';
        echo json_encode($data[2]) . '<br><br>';
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
****Chicago: 45 fog****
{"Mon":[44,"fog"],"Tue":[42,"sleet"],"Wed":[40,"rain"],"Thu":[44,"cloudy"],"Fri":[45,"cloudy"]}
****Paris: 73 sunny****
{"Mon":[75,"sunny"],"Tue":[75,"sunny"],"Wed":[68,"cloudy"],"Thu":[66,"cloudy"],"Fri":[60,"rain"]}
****Calgary: -8 snow****
{"Mon":[-7,"snow"],"Tue":[-10,"snow"],"Wed":[-3,"sleet"],"Thu":[0,"cloudy"],"Fri":[3,"sunny"]}
```